# Powershell: Convert "Get-Place Localities" to a display name

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I have a script that's exporting all room display names from Exchange Online alongside the room list they belong to.

Problem is, that "Get-Place -identity | Select-Object Localities" returns the primary SMTP address of a room list, whereas I'd like this script to use display names instead.

Is there any way I could convert this within the script?

```
$rooms = Get-Mailbox -Filter '(RecipientTypeDetails -eq "RoomMailbox")' -ResultSize Unlimited

$report = foreach ($room in $rooms)
{
    Get-Place -Identity "$($room.DisplayName)" -ResultSize Unlimited | Select-Object DisplayName,City,Localities
    Write-Host $room.DisplayName processed
}
$report | Export-Csv C:\Temp\Places.csv -UseCulture -NoTypeInformation -Encoding Unicode
```

Answer (score 0):

The column's name is $room.name instead of $room.DisplayName

It's work better in my side !